# pulling out list from wordpress post

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to pull out the list (ul) element from my wordpress post(s) so I can put it in a different location.

My current css pulls out the images and blockqute and puts just the text

html

```
<?php
  $content = preg_replace('/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/', '', get_the_content());
  $content = preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*>)/', '', $content);
  $content = wpautop($content); // Add paragraph-tags
  $content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content); // remove empty paragraphs
    echo $content;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a friendly reminder is that it is generally not recommended to parse html with regex.
If you would like to do that anyway you could try like this:

```
$pattern = '~<ul>(.*?)</ul>~s';
```

So in your code it would look like this:

```
preg_match_all('/(~<ul>(.*?)</ul>~s)/', $content, $ulElements);
```

And then for removing it from the original string:

```
preg_replace('/(~<ul>(.*?)</ul>~s)/', '', $content);
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with what you mean by regex

Comment: Regex is what you are using to parse the content in your code. Regex stands for Regular expression and you can learn more about Regex here http://www.regular-expressions.info/.
Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php and you see that it says "preg_replace — Perform a regular expression search and replace" as the description of the function.

Comment: Oh ok, I haven't heard that side and thought it was an effective approach. What is a better way?

Comment: The best approach would be to find a way to not have to parse your html with regex, how that is achieved is highly dependent on how your current setup is. I would guess that you are parsing the content from the wisysig, if possible it would be better to divide the content you are getting in different fields. One way to do that is with ACF (advanced custom fields). I hope that helps you somehow.

Comment: ok thank you. I have it set so that It all can be written in the post content, and then each piece is picked out and placed in different spots on the page through echo, etc