# putting images and blockquote back in/on page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following code which takes out elements from my wordpress post.

```
<?php
            $content = get_the_content();
            $content = wpautop($content);

            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->loadHTML(get_the_content(), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

            $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

            foreach ($xpath->query('//blockquote') as $node) {
                $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
            }

            foreach ($xpath->query('//img') as $node) {
                $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
            }

            foreach( $xpath->query('//p[not(node())]') as $node ) {
                $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
            }

            $content = $doc->saveHTML($doc);

?>
```

This strips everything but the text and I echo the content to get the altered content

```
echo $content
```

EDIT:  I want the images and blockquote removed automatically from the post so I can put them in a different part of the page. Instead of having them displayed as they appear in the admin panel.

Comment: I am not clear, what actually you are looking for. Can you please make it more clear ?

Comment: Then remove the part that removes the images / block quotes?

Comment: Edited the question. I want to remove them from the content so I can put ONLY the images in a different spot on the page and ONLY the blockquote on a different part. The code I have puts only the <p> text of the content

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions to the rescue.

First, load story:

```
$content = get_the_content();
```

Next, create patterns to locate:

```
$bpattern '/(<blockquote)([^>]*)(>)([^<]*)(<\/blockquote>)/';
$ipattern = '/(<img)([^>]*)(>)([^<]*)(<\/img>)/';
```

Next, put all blockquotes and images to a new array via preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all( $bpattern, $content, $blockquotes );
preg_match_all( $ipattern, $content, $imgs );
```

Now, remove those items from $content via preg_replace:

```
preg_replace( array( $bpattern, $ipattern ), '', $content );
```

Finally, the `$blockquotes` and `$imgs` arrays will be arrays of match arrays, use `foreach` and `[0]` to output the entire element:

```
foreach( $blockquotes[0] as $bquote ) {
     echo $bquote;
}

foreach( $imgs[0] as $img ) {
     echo $img;
}
```

Comment: I should note that this will only work if the blockquote and img tags are well-formed. This will be the case in WordPress if you use the editor's buttons to add them and don't mess around with them in the visual editor. However, it will NOT address captions and other markup that surrounds images embedded via the Media browser / Insert media button. For that you need to find the containing div, which is a different regex.

Comment: My issue is that I was told creating my own 'regex' (using preg_replace) was bad practice and can be really buggy

Comment: Stop listening to whomever told you that.

Comment: lol, fair enough. I just not sure what he meant. the comment was made in my prior related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585007/pulling-out-list-from-wordpress-post